# How to remove the product price and subtotal amount in the shopping cart page in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

Only i need to show the number of quantity items in the shopping cart page.

If any one know the answer please share the exact code and folder structure. since I'm new to magneto.

shopping cart page screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

find and edit **form.phtml** in the following location of Magneto 2-3  :

> app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/form.phtml

and you can easily edit **`<th>`** html element of **Total** and **SubTotal** :

```
   <caption class="table-caption"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Shopping Cart Items')) ?></caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col item" scope="col">
                 <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Item')) ?></span></th>
                <th class="col price" scope="col">
                 <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')) ?></span></th>  // remove this line for Price
                <th class="col qty" scope="col">
                 <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span></th>
                <th class="col subtotal" scope="col">
                 <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Subtotal')) ?></span></th> // remove this line for Subtotal
            </tr>
```

Comment: how to override the form.phtml file

Comment: @RameshR locate and change the file in the file explorer of your host panel. if your magneto is hosted then you need to edit this file in the host.

Comment: i have tried other answers in magento stack exchange forum and its working fine. thanks for your suggestion.